# Eclipse-Marketplace Error

Tags: eclipse-marketplace

Once i go to Eclipse Marketplace option i get this error message:
    MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
    Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?product=org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product&os=linux&runtime.version=3.6.0.v20100505&client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&java.version=1.6.0_26&product.version=1.3.2.20110218-0812&        ws=gtk.
No route to host

This in my linux machine can i know why am i getting this message, i am not able to choose any new softwares from Marketplace

Answer (score 2):

Please, add this line on eclipse ini, restart eclipse, open Marketplace and good installations:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.service.DefaultCatalogService.url=https://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
```

This problem is that link without ssl is not working.
For me that is working normal.

Comment: @user4516987, I still get this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090792/searching-on-eclipse-market-place

Answer (score 0):

Try removing RelaventKnowledge software from your machine. Mine is Windows 10. I am not getting that error once i removed that software from the machine.