# Eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I am using Eclipse (4.2, Juno & 4.3, Kepler) on mac OS X. I am trying to use Eclipse Marketplace but  it gives me the error of "Unexpected exception: URI is not absolute". Is this a general issue because their website is down or is there anything wrong in my Eclipse?

Thank you for your help,
Somayeh

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: no, I am using SVN Eclipse from repository

Comment: so you're not using the stable release, but the nightly build, right?

Comment: yes, I am. Sorry for replying so late.

Comment: np. nightly builds are unstable. Try using a stable release instead.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue with version 3.6.0.RELEASE.

Comment: try another time, I could get what I wanted the day after.

Comment: View my post for that on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511349/eclipse-marketplace-error

Good work,