# Searching on Eclipse Market Place

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

Everytime I open my Eclipse IDE's Marketplace. Then search with the keyword "spring"... I keep on getting this error:

[image: ecli]

Help please.

Thanks.

Comment: hello pal, the same problem with MarketPlace-Client , I am trying to search pydev, but the app is showing a similar dialog-box, I am on kubuntu-1904-Linux, eclipse JEE 2019-06

Comment: Its seams a problem with the way MarketPlace-Client is tryng to connect to the server , http isntead of https

Comment: [I can also reproduce this issue with the current and an older Eclipse/MPC version, so I guess it's on the server side.](https://twitter.com/howlger/status/1176756786923233281) Please [report it to the Eclipse MPC project](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=MPC).

Comment: Clearing the cache don't fix the problem `$ ./eclipse -clean`

Comment: @christianbueno.1 Could you please add an answer by saying that it is probably a server side issue (which will be hopefully fixed soon) and by referring to the [bug that you have reported](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551442)? So other questions can marked as [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58094607/6505250).

Comment: @howlger, confirmed. it was just a server side issue. which I thought also yesterday. I also thought of there were some feature/modules/api endpoints being dropped or unsupported actually. but thankfully it isn't the issue. I can now search spring in the marketplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

This was a **temporary server-side** issue that has **meanwhile** been **fixed**. Please try again.

See [Eclipse bug 551442](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551442)

---

Same problem on kubuntu 1904 Linux, Eclipse JEE 2019-06, I am trying to install pydev, but it is not possible because is there a request problem
[image]

It is the url of the request :http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p/search/apachesolr_search/pydev?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.7.7.v20190521-1752&os=linux&ws=gtk&nl=en_US&java.version=11.0.4&product=org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product&product.version=4.12.0.I20190605-1800&runtime.version=3.15.300.v20190508-0543&platform.version=4.12.0.v20190605-1800

Eclipse says that all websites is working good , status ok https://status.eclipse.org/

It appears in the website when trying to search pydev
[image]

**A quick solution is**
In MarketPlace-Client select the Popular tab and scroll  down , then you will find Spring, in my case there is pydev too, then install button.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much :)! yes indeed a server side issue. which I also had suspected.