# Difficulty in adding GITHUB to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I am trying to add dependency of GitHub to my eclipse IDE but the market place shows the following error if I search using 'git' keyword.

MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p/search/apachesolr_search/git?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.7.7.v20190521-1752&os=linux&ws=gtk&nl=en_IN&java.version=12.0.2&product=org.eclipse.sdk.ide&product.version=4.11.0.I20190307-0500&runtime.version=3.15.200.v20190301-1641&platform.version=4.11.0.v20190307-0500: HTTP Server 'Internal Error': http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p/search/apachesolr_search/git?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.7.7.v20190521-1752&os=linux&ws=gtk&nl=en_IN&java.version=12.0.2&product=org.eclipse.sdk.ide&product.version=4.11.0.I20190307-0500&runtime.version=3.15.200.v20190301-1641&platform.version=4.11.0.v20190307-0500
HTTP Server 'Internal Error': http://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p/search/apachesolr_search/git?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.7.7.v20190521-1752&os=linux&ws=gtk&nl=en_IN&java.version=12.0.2&product=org.eclipse.sdk.ide&product.version=4.11.0.I20190307-0500&runtime.version=3.15.200.v20190301-1641&platform.version=4.11.0.v20190307-0500
HttpComponents connection error response code 500.

Comment: This seems to be a server side [issue which will be hopefully fixed soon](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551442).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching on Eclipse Market Place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58090792/searching-on-eclipse-market-place)

Comment: This was a temporary server-side issue that has meanwhile been fixed. Please try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran in this issue myself this morning.

This seems to be a Problem with the Marketplace itself. If you use the search functionality on https://marketplace.eclipse.org you'll get a `Search is temporarily unavailable. If the problem persists, please contact the site administrator.` Message.

Hopefully this might be a temporary Problem. This Bug has also been reported already: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy%20failed%20with%20an%20error.

My solution has to directly install the desired software from the Update-URL I found using google and the "Help"/"Install new Software" Menuitem.